# How to dynamically access/ define a table row with pageobject gem?

Tags: watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a table like this

```
<iframe title="ManageLegs">
    <table title="Leg Details">
        <tr>
            <th />
            <th class="headerRow"><div>Dep Date</div></th>
            <th class="headerRow"><div>ETD</div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2015-02-01</td>
            <td>0900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2015-02-15</td>
            <td>1100</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</iframe>
```

Each row has its number in the first cell.
Thing is, that the number of rows varies, and when defining the PageObject for that site, I don´t know how many rows there will be.

Currently I use this code on the PageObject to access the table cells

```
in_iframe(:title => 'ManageLegs') do |frame|
    table(:leg_details, title: 'Leg Details', :frame => frame)

    # 1st leg
    text_field(:departure_date1) { leg_details_element['1']['Dep Date'].text_field_element }

    # 2nd leg
    text_field(:departure_date2) { leg_details_element['2']['Dep Date'].text_field_element }

    # 3rd leg ...
    # ...
end
```

But this is not DRY at all.
Any advice on how to simplify this?

Thx in advance,
Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I like to define the rows as widgets. This proivdes a descriptive API for the page.

The Leg class to represent a row:

```
class Leg < PageObject::Elements::TableRow
  def index
    cell_element(index: 0).text
  end

  def dep_date
    cell_element(index: 1).text
  end

  def etd
    cell_element(index: 2).text
  end
end
PageObject.register_widget :leg, Leg, :tr
```

The page object:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  in_iframe(:title => 'ManageLegs') do |frame|
    legs(:leg) do
      table_element(:title => 'Leg Details', :frame => frame)
        .leg_elements(:tag_name => 'tr')[1..-1]
    end
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
page = MyPage.new(browser)
page.leg_elements.each do |leg|
  p leg.index
  p leg.dep_date
  p leg.etd
end
#=> "1"
#=> "2015-02-01"
#=> "0900"
#=> "2"
#=> "2015-02-15"
#=> "1100"
```

Comment: This seems like more code than the other answer, but in the long run it can be very very handy to have a single object like 'leg_elements' in your code that holds all the data from the table.  it can make walking through validations much cleaner, especially if you are using something like cucumber and the validation step is passing in a cucumber table that you then compare with your the object that holds the actual results

Comment: Thx Justin, this looks very promising.
Unfortunately it fails when trying to execute, giving this error `undefined method `legs' for CharterInquirySavedPage:Class (NoMethodError)`
which refers to this snippet of code: `legs(:leg) do`

Comment: It worked locally for me. Did you register the widget - the line `PageObject.register_widget :leg, Leg, :tr`? Also what version of the page-object gem are you using? The widget collections (ie `legs`) is a more recent feature.

Comment: I missed to register the widget, it´s working now. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just write a method in your page:

```ruby
in_iframe(:title => 'ManageLegs') do |frame|
  table(:leg_details, title: 'Leg Details', :frame => frame)      
end

def departure_date(number)
  leg_details_element[number]['Dep Date'].text_field_element
end
```